# Eclipse Plugin - Make a menu Item visible only when a particular element is selected

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

What I want is to add a menu item to Package Explorer and the Project Explorer of Eclipse which is visible only when I right click on a project Element.

What I have done so far is- Added a menu item to both Package and Project Explorer, but they visible on a right click from anywhere.

What I want is the command to only appear if the Project Element is Right Clicked from the project/package explorer.

I don't want the menu item to be visible if someone right clicks on the Package or any folder in any project.

Ie.

```
Right Click on Project -> Menu Item Visible
Right Click on any other resource in the project -> Menu Item not present
```

Is this possible by adding  attributes ? I am confused as to how to use it. Do I need to add a click listener for the the Package and Project Explorers ?

I am writing this plugin for Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: Which extension point at you using for the menu items?

Comment: @greg-449 `org.eclipse.ui.menus`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the `visibleWhen` element of the `command` in the `org.eclipse.ui.menus` extension point to control visibility.

For a project you need to check if the current selection adapts to the `IProject` interface:

```xml
<visibleWhen
       checkEnabled="false">
   <iterate>
      <adapt
          type="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
      </adapt>
   </iterate>
</visibleWhen>
```

Which is iterating through the objects in the current selection.

The selected objects will be some user interface object belonging to the current view, usually these do not directly implement the `IProject` interface. Instead it may be possible to 'adapt' the object to the interface using the Eclipse adapter manager (see the `IAdapterManager`, `IAdapterFactory`, `IAdaptable` interfaces). The `adapt` element is testing if the selection object can be adapted.

Comment: @greg_449 Could you just explain the code above, I am really confused about how <visibleWhen> works. Why is there checkEnabled=false ? What are we iterating over in the <iterate> tag ? What does adapting mean, does it mean somewhere down the inheritance chain IProject must exists ? Which variable are we checking for the adapt in the <iterate> tag ?

Sorry but this is all very confusing to me, would be great if you could just explain it

Comment: `checkEnabled` is described fully in the Eclipse help I see no reason to repeat it here. Added some more info on iterate and adapt to the answer.

Comment: `checkEnabled` checks the enabled state of the command ? What does that even mean ? How can a command be disabled ? AFAIK only the menu item or any other widget can be disabled. Also `checkEnabled` states that there should be no sub elements, how can a command have subElements ?

Comment: It is talking about the command declared with `org.eclipse.ui.commands` which is only enabled if there is an active handler. No sub elements is saying that `visibleWhen checkEnabled="true"` can't have any sub elements.

Comment: Okay there is one small problem. When I right click on a blank project or package explorer the menu item is still there. But it is not visible when I click on packages or other invalid selections. Correct me if I am wrong but should I put a NOT NULL check ? I have already added ifEmpty=false, but it made no difference.

Comment: What do you mean by 'blank project'? An empty project is still a project.

Comment: Sorry wrong wording. What I meant that if there no projects open in the Package/Project Explorer, then if I right click the menu item is there in the command menu

Comment: The test is on whatever the current selection is, it isn't restricted to specific views. Possibly using `iterate ifEmpty="false"` may help.

Answer (score 0):

checkEnabled indicates whether to check the enableWhen constraint of the handler before making the pop menu visible.
If the checkEnabled is true, the eclipse checks the corresponding Handler's enabled when when criteria, if the criteria is satisfied, the the popup menu is visible, else not.
If checkEnabled is false, then the popup menu menu would be visible without checking the handler's enableWhen criteria.However the visibleWhen can have its own expression for enabling or disabling the menu.